# How to implement the Sumproduct fuctionality using Apex class

Tags: apex, class

In our project we need to use the Sumproduct Function (Similar to Excel SUMPRODUCT function).

How do I implement it using Apex class.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code, this will give an Idea to implement.

```
Integer total = 0;
//Take two maps expecting you need to product 2 columns
//Column 1 and 2 can be integer or any of the valid data type
// put your values into the maps by looping through your values
//Assuming you are ready with the maps data
Map<Id, Column1>  map1= new Map<Id, column1>();
Map<Id, Column2>  map1= new Map<Id, column2>();

for(id i: map1.keySet()){

    if(map2.containsKey(i)){
           integer prod = o; 
           prod = (map1.get(i) * map2.get(i));
           total = total +prod; 
     }
}
//This is so genreral idea just serves as tip to start your code
```